# Variable output voltage regulation - does this solution make sense?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, darlington

I want to use a switching power supply that has a fixed 24VDC output. I want to add a simple circuit that will give me an adjustable voltage between 0-24VDC. The power supply allows the consumption of about 2A and I would like to have such a current in the entire adjustment range. I thought about such a circuit based on a darlington transistor, which is controlled by a potentiometer (divider R5/R6). Overcurrent protection is still missing. Does this arrangement make sense?
[image]

Comment: *Does this arrangement make sense?* <-- not really; at half the voltage output and 2 amps load current, the Darlington would dissipate 24 watts and, the output will have poor regulation (if that's an important thing to you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this arrangement make sense?

Does and doesn't.

Does, because the arrangement is basically a linear regulator with local feedback. You apply a voltage to the base and expect two V<sub>BE</sub> drop less at the output.

Doesn't, because the output voltage depends on the V<sub>BE</sub> of the transistors, and V<sub>BE</sub> of the output transistor changes with collector (load) current as well as with temperature. There's no compensation network implemented in your circuit. So it won't work as a voltage regulator i.e. the output voltage will drop as the load draws more current.

Answer (score 1):

It will make sense if your load on vout never changes. If it does change, you will need some kind of feedback to the voltage divider to let the voltage adjust with respect to the load.

Typically a good regulator will look something like this:
[image]
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator

But you might be able to modify your circuit to something simpler depending on what kind of regulation you need:
[image]
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator

Comment: thanks for the advice. I want to go simple, so I will try the sec Don regulator circuit. I assume, that I still need to keep the Darlington configuration AND add this "transistor regulator" circuit at the output?

Comment: Yeah, the darlington might give you issues because of the stacked BJT's and it having a high gain, but you could always try it.